# How Can i test creating a Blob and saving a file as csv using Mocha-enzyme?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, enzyme

I would like to test creation of a blob of csv format and saving it on button click. The code snippet for it:

```
     const blob = new Blob(csvData, {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
     saveAs(blob, fileName + ".csv");
```

i simulated click as follows to test some other custom function called from the same click handler:

```
    wrapper.find('Button').simulate('click');      
    expect(filterDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

running the test gave an error saying :

ReferenceError: Blob is not defined

Is there any way to test the creation of Blob and saving the File ?

Comment: What browser are you running your test suite in?

Comment: i am not running it on  a browser .

Comment: Then you'd need to mock or find polyfills for all the browser-specific APIs (at which point you have to question the value of the tests)

Comment: i am somewhat new to Mocha tests , i dint understand your comment.